# GetTemplateChild returns null in different project

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've created a `FilteredComboBox` which derives from the standard WPF `comboBox`. This new `UserControl` works fine so far in the original test application in which it was designed.
Now that I've copied the class over to my main application I'm getting *null reference exceptions* when trying to access the `PART_EditableTextBox` child of the `ComboBox`:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        EditableTextBox.SelectionChanged += EditableTextBox_SelectionChanged;
        ItemsPopup.Focusable = true;
    }

    private TextBox EditableTextBox
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox"); }
    }
```

The problem occurs in the line where I want to add an `SelectionChanged` event. When doing some reseach it was always suggested to wait until `ApplyTemplate` is finished which is basically done in the `base.OnApplyTemplate();`

I checked the underlying template in my main application and it should contain the `PART_EditableTextBox`.

Any ideas on what might be wrong here or what I can do for further investigation?

UPDATE: I found the problem after checking some of Xavier's suggestions. The problem with the PART_EditableTextBox is that it is only available when the ComboBox is defined as

```
IsEditable = True
```

Which I have to admit was not the case in the second project that I mentioned. If the ComboBox is not editable then it simply does not have a EditableTextBox :-/

Thanks for the support guys...

Comment: The code looks OK.  Just a wild guess, well, maybe `PART_EditableTextBox` is the variable name,  so the correct code should `GetTemplateChild(PART_EditableTextBox);`

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you are getting the template that you expect. If you are sure the template has the named part you want, but attempting to retrieve it returns null, it is almost certainly not applied to the control when you attempt to access it.

You mentioned that the problem started when you moved the control from one assembly to another. Perhaps the assembly you moved it to is not setup properly for what you are trying to do.

For example, are you expecting the template to be applied automatically as part of a default theme? If so, is the style in the right place in the assembly (in or referenced from themes/generic.xaml), and are you properly defining the [ThemeInfo attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.themeinfoattribute.aspx) in your AssemblyInfo.cs file? (Also, are you overriding the metadata in the user control to use the correct resource key?)

If you are instead applying the template explicitly somewhere, then the default from the base class might be getting applied before yours, so you are crashing while applying the default and never getting to the point where yours is applied.

There are several things that could be wrong, and it is hard to know which it is without simply checking everything. Hopefully something I said will give you a hint about the issue.

---

Note: As a matter of practice, I always add null checks after attempting to retrieve template parts. You can never be sure how the control might get used, and what templates might be applied in different scenarios. For example, anyone using the control can override the template and not specify the part you expect. In my opinion, it is better to have the control not function as designed than to crash the application.

Note 2: Rather than have a property that looks up the template part every time you want to access it, you should probably look it up once in OnApplyTemplate and store it as a member variable. That saves the template lookup every time you access the control from code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making this a custom control vs. a UserControl? I think the problem you're facing might be due to the timing of when a UserControl is initialized in the object lifecycle.

In the case below, you're trying to wire up the event handler before the part is accessible.

One way to get around problems like this is to use the Dispatcher to wait until its safe to wire-up the event handler.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    GetTemplateParts();
    ItemsPopup.Focusable = true;
}

protected void GetTemplateParts()
{
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Loaded, 
            new Action(() => 
            { 
                EditableTextBox.SelectionChanged += EditableTextBox_SelectionChanged;
            }));
}
```